# header element's height is looking different than the design I have

Tags: html, css

Header (has a background image) element's height is looking different than the design I have. I am checking this with "perfect pixel" chrome extension. I want to fix the height of the header element according to the image size and overlay image(perfect pixel). Actual image size is 1440x819px. Header element's height is looking 80px bigger than the overlay image. See full code in codepen.

[You can find the image here the problem I am facing](https://i.imgur.com/sbmgUBh.jpg):

[image]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/alrahat123/pen/poqGaWB)

[I want this result which is 1440x1207px - header and create a memory section](https://i.imgur.com/1m4BXTR.jpg):

[image]

```css
header {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/d6N8fbO.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left top;
  min-width: 1440px;
  height: 819px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-1">
      <div class="col col-lg-11">
        <nav class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Flights</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-lg-7">
        <div class="contact-us right">
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-2">
      <div class="col col-lg-7">
        <div class="left-side">
          <h2 class="title">Travel to your dream destination</h2>
          <p class="p-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum sus pendisse ultrices gravida. </p>
          <a href="#">Reserve Ticket</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-lg-11">
        <div class="right-side img-container">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xUIyDXA.jpg" alt="Reserve Tickets" class="img-responsive" width="662" height="419">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `background-size: cover;` — You're explicitly scaling the background image!

Comment: @Quentin how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you describe what should happen if we view this website on a very wide screen? If the screen is 3840 pixels wide your 1440 pixels image cannot cover the back of the website from right to left. It will either need to stretch, or it will need to get centered.

Comment: @Quentin I have tried several value for background-size, and without the property, nothing is working. I don't think background-size is causing any issue. the result is same.

Comment: @ReneVanDenBerg You are right. I have set background position to center center and is using contain for background size. is it ok?

Comment: The height is still the same.

Comment: That will keep the height of the image consistent no matter what width the screen is. Hope that fixes your issue!

Comment: @ReneVanDenBerg The height issue is still not fixed. The problem I had with height remains the same.

Comment: For full code, check codepen.

Comment: @ReneVanDenBerg Header height is greater than the overlay image(perfect pixel) which is 80px(819px-739px). I have tried using 739px for height but the background image looks different than the overlay image. When I add bootstrap 3 css file(only) to the html document, height issue is fixed. But I want height as actual image size and according to overlay image without bootstrap and want to know what is causing the issue and need solution.

Comment: The height issue is fixed. Thank you everyone for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
header .row-1 {
    margin-top: 79px; /* Set margin-top to padding-top */
}
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me why should I use padding in this case?  When to use margin and padding?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).